# Manually Enable Compression Using httpModule

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm trying to enable gzip compression on a site on our work intranet. Unfortunately, I don't have access to IIS, so any changes I make have been through web.config.

The server is running IIS 6 and .NET 2.0.

I enabled compression by adding an httpmodule

```
public class EnableCompression : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += 
            (new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));

    }

    private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        context.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-encoding"] = true;
    }

}
```

I registered in the web.config...

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="EnableCompression" type="EnableCompression"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Well, the above worked fine, except javascript and css files do not get compressed. From what I have found, I would have to add .js and .css to the application mappings in IIS 6, but of course I can't do that.

Apparently this can be done via the web.config file, but I don't know how to do that.

How can I enable compression for .js and .css files?

Comment: Your code has two bugs. First, you should check to see if the incoming request has the `Accept-Encoding` HTTP header set, and if so, whether gzip is one of the allowed values (the Framework also supports deflate, using `DeflateStream`, which actually results in smaller output). Second, the `VaryByHeaders` setting is only valid when you have output caching enabled, and tells the runtime to vary the output cache by the specified header. In your case, you will end up with multiple copies of the same compressed page in cache for each different setting of `Accept-Encoding` (including none).

Comment: Thatnks, i'll be sure to incorporate your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS6, static code is not processed by managed `HttpModules`; it requires a native ISAPI.

One trick you can use is to convert your *.js and *.css files into dynamic files. You do this by changing them to be *.aspx, and set the ContentType to the right MIME type. For example:

```
this.Response.ContentType = "application/x-javascript";
```

The only other trick is to set `StyleSheetTheme=""` in the Page directive in the markup file. Otherwise, the runtime will insist on a `<head>` section in the document. You can enable output caching to minimize the performance impact.

I wrote a blog post about this on the JS side, in case it helps (CSS is similar, just with a different MIME type): http://www.12titans.net/p/dynamic-javascript.aspx

Unfortunately, this requires changing the name of your JS and CSS files in your app, but if you want compression and don't have access to IIS, I don't think there's a way around that.

If you want to keep the *.js and *.css extensions, you can do so by adding a handler for them in your web.config. For example:

```
<compilation>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".css" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>

<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.css" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"
       validate="true"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

This helps from a naming perspective, but not performance; the files will still be dynamic -- they are basically *.aspx files, but with a different extension. It also doesn't work correctly with ASP.NET Themes, since pages in the Themes folder can't be dynamic, regardless of their extension.

Comment: Be careful about converting to dynamic.  IIS is much faster at serving static files than dynamic (kernel mode).  Only consider that if your app is dominated by bandwidth concerns.

Comment: You can make dynamic files as fast as statics after the first request by enabling output caching, which in turn enables http.sys caching. Just keep to the limitations of what http.sys will cache, such as no query strings, no dynamic cache invalidation, etc.

Comment: Im disappointed to learn that i wont be able to compress my js and css files. Id rather not go through the trouble of converting the files to dynamic. I will definitely enable output caching, i just didnt want the page to take forever to load the first time.

Comment: You can control static compression from web.config, but only with IIS7+ (system.webServer/urlCompression). There are ways to mitigate increases to load times on first access. For example, you can have a startup script that loads the page when your AppPool recycles. Using a precompiled site also helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @RickNZ's answer:

Be careful about converting to dynamic. IIS is much faster at serving static files than dynamic (kernel mode). Only consider that if your app is dominated by bandwidth concerns.

One other option is to look into CDNs for static content (content delivery networks).  Azure, Amazon, Akamai and others offer services.  That's a very fast geo-located friendly way of serving static files.

Comment: Ill look into a CDN. Since the webserver  we use is local, i wonder if it would be faster to download the full payload locally or the compressed files from a CDN

Comment: If it's local then probably not better - CDN helps with web site in the cloud and excels when globally accessed.